# loosing dict content as soon as am out of loop in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Team: need some assistance..
sub: loosing dict content as soon as am out of loop. dict is populated with loop vars that are added to dict using subscript approach.
below foo() is always getting executed because the `team_oncall_dict`  is empty outside. any hint how can I retain it as it was inside loop?

```
 def askduty_oncall(self, *args):
        session = APISession(PD_API_KEY, default_from=PD_USER_EMAIL)
        total = 1 #true or false
        limit = 40
        teamteamnm = "Team Test Team"
        team_esp_name = “Team Test Escalation Policy"
        teamteamid = ""
        teamesplcyid = ""
        team_oncall_dict = {}

        if args:
            offset = args[0]
            total_teams = args[1]
            
            if offset <= total_teams:
                print("\nfunc with args with new offset {} called\n".format(offset))
                teams = session.get('/teams?limit={0}&total={1}&offset={2}'.format(limit,total,offset))
            else:
                print("Reached max teams, no more team records to pull")
                return
        else:
            print("\nFunc with no args called, hence pull first set of {} teams as defined by limit var\n".format(limit))
            teams = session.get('/teams?limit={0}&total={1}'.format(limit,total))
        
        if not teams.ok:
            return
        else:          
            tj = teams.json()
            tjd = tj['teams']
            for adict in tjd:
                if not adict['name'] == teamteamnm:
                    continue
                elif adict['name'] == teamteamnm:
                    teamteamid = adict['id']
                    print("\nFound team..\nFetched",adict['name'], "id: {0}".format(teamteamid))
                    print("Pull escalation policy for team '{}':'{}'".format(teamteamnm,teamteamid))
                    esclp = session.get('/escalation_policies?total={0}&team_ids%5B%5D={1}'.format(total,teamteamid))
                    if not esclp.ok:
                        print("Pulling Escalation polices for team '{}' failed".format(teamteamnm))
                        return
                    else:
                        ep = esclp.json()
                        epj = esclp.json()['escalation_policies']
                        if not epj:
                            print("Escalation polices for team '{}' not defined".format(teamteamnm))
                            return
                        else:
                            for adict2 in epj:
                                if not adict2['summary'] == team_esp_name:
                                    continue
                                else:
                                    print("***************FOUND FOUND********************")
                                    teamesplcyid = adict2['id']
                                    print("\nFetched {} id: {}\n".format(team_esp_name, teamesplcyid))
                                    oncalls = session.get('/oncalls?total={0}&escalation_policy_ids%5B%5D={1}'.format(total,teamesplcyid))
                                    if not oncalls.ok:
                                        print(“issue “with oncalls)
                                        return
                                    else:
                                        ocj = oncalls.json()['oncalls']
                                        for adict3 in ocj:
                                            print("\n")
                                            print(adict3['escalation_level'])
                                            if i['escalation_level'] == 1:
                                                print(adict3['schedule']['summary'], adict3['user']['summary'])
                                                team_oncall_dict[adict3['schedule']['summary']] = adict3['user']['summary']
                                                print(team_oncall_dict)
                                                return team_oncall_dict


    if not team_oncall_dict: #part of func def
       do foo()
```

output

```
foo stuff
```

sample data is a list of dicts

```
[{'escalation_policy': {'id': 'P8RKTEE', 'type': 'escalation_policy_reference', 'summary': 'Team Escalation Policy'}, 'escalation_level': 3, 'schedule': None, 'user': {'id': 'PX8XYFT', 'type': 'user_reference', 'summary': 'M1’}, 'start': None, 'end': None}, 
{'escalation_policy': {'id': 'P8RKTEE', 'type': 'escalation_policy_reference', 'summary': 'Team Escalation Policy'}, 'escalation_level': 1, 'schedule': None, 'user': {'id': 'PKXXVJI', 'type': 'user_reference', 'summary': ‘R1’}, 'start': None, 'end': None}, 
{'escalation_policy': {'id': 'P8RKTEE', 'type': 'escalation_policy_reference', 'summary': 'Team’}, 'escalation_level': 2, 'schedule': None, 'user': {'d': 'PN8F9PC', 'type': 'user_reference’,'summary': ‘T1’}],'start': None, 'end': None}]
```

btw: above is 4th inner loop.
so flow is like this diagramatically.

```
def func1()
team_oncall_dict = {}

  loop1
     loop2
        loop3
           loop4
             ...
             team_oncall_dict
   if not team_oncall_dict:
     print("dict is empty")
```

output

```
dict is empty
```

Comment: Is `if not team_oncall_dict:  print("dict is empty")` outside the `func1`? If yes, do you declare `team_oncall_dict` outside the function as well?

Comment: You have some indentation issues, but the problem you're describing is likely due to you defining the dictionary as a local variable inside your function (the `def` part) and then when the function exits, the local variable is cleaned up and no longer exists. Always share your actual code, or a working example that you and others can actually run that demonstrates the problem. The 'pseudo-code' you shared hides the problem. Alternatively, whatever you're returning is an empty dictionary, but it's hard to say without actual code.

Comment: added actual code.

Comment: `if not team_oncall_dict:` - this is not calling a function, it's just checking its truth value, which is `True` for a function. You may want something like `if not team_oncall_dict():` - note that your code also has characters in there that aren't supposed to be in code. Use an appropriate editor for writing code, not something like Word or Wordpad.

Comment: how do you execute `askduty_oncall()`? If you run it as normal function thne maybe at the end of function you should use `return team_oncall_dict` and run it as `team_oncall_dict = askduty_oncall()`

Comment: They issue was dictionary was local to the function and I had to make it global I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

t was local vs global. fixed it by declaring the `team_oncall_dict` globally outside the function.

intead of

```
def func1()
team_oncall_dict = {}
```

```
team_oncall_dict = {}
def func1()
```